# Replacing NSStatusBarButton NSView to disable vibrancy

Tags: swift, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I am currently trying to reduce the default vibrancy that is added to NSStatusBarItems icons in Mac OS. I understand this can be achieved by changing the allowsVibrancy attribute. However, since that is read-only on NSView, I need to extend that class and override the allowsVibrancy method.

```
class NoneVibrancyView: NSView
{
    override var allowsVibrancy: Bool { return false }
}
```

Currently my icon is still looking like allowsVibrancy is activated. I am wondering if Im replacing my NSView correctly. Here is my code:

```
let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system

statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)

let noneVibrancyView = NoneVibrancyView(frame: statusBarItem.button!.frame)

statusBarItem.button?.addSubview(noneVibrancyView)

statusBarItem.button?.title = ""

let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "My Status Menu Bar")

statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu
```

Comment: Can you check if you parent NSButton is still vibrant = true?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. statusBarItem.button?.allowsVibrancy = true. So that is not what I want it to be. Do you know how I can change that? @Maschina

Comment: To my understanding, the vibrancy is controlled by the parent view. So if the parent has vibrancy allowed, the subviews cannot influence it. Out of curiosity, can you try to sub-class the NSButton and set allowVibrancy = false?

Comment: Yes, but how can I replace the button on the NSStatusBarItem?

Comment: You may extend the NSStatusBarButton: `extension NSStatusBarButton { override var allowsVibrancy: Bool { return false } }`

Comment: I tried that but xcode gives the following warning: "Overriding property must be as accessible as the declaration it overrides"

Comment: Nevermind I needed to add 'open' as it declaration within NSView. It is now working! thanks! Wanna answer it so I can approve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206966/discussion-between-maschina-and-user1391281).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vibrancies of subviews will be overridden by its parent's vibrancy. Therefore, it is required to set the vibrancy of the status bar button that is parent of your custom view (due to `addSubview()`).

Since the button of the status item is automatically generated, you may have to use extensions for that:

```
extension NSStatusBarButton { 
    override open var allowsVibrancy: Bool { return false } 
}
```